# Customer service and service factory not registering in ZF3

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework3, zf3

For some reason, I don't think that my `'service_manager'` config is being read properly.  This is mostly pretty much a brand-new skeleton checkout.  Maybe a days work.

I did another one recently and tried comparing.  I can't figure out where I went wrong.

Under the anonymous function pointed to by `Controller\DbBuilderController::class => function(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName) {` the line `$userService = $container->get(\Application\Service\UserService::class);` causes an error: `Unable to resolve service "Application\Service\UserService" to a factory; are you certain you provided it during configuration?`

I have tried changing `\Application\Service\UserService::class` to short, silly, literal strings so I'm confident that the service is not being registered.

I'm not sure why that would happen.  Any takers?

```
<?php
namespace Application;

use Zend\Mvc\Application;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\LazyControllerAbstractFactory;
use Zend\Router\Http\Literal;
use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver;

return [
    'service_manager' => [
        'factories' => [
            \Application\Service\UserService::class => \Application\Service\Factory\UserServiceFactory::class
        ],
    ],
    'doctrine' => [
        'driver' => [
            __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => [
                'class' => AnnotationDriver::class,
                'cache' => 'array',
                'paths' => [__DIR__ . '/../src/Entity']
            ],
            'orm_default' => [
                'drivers' => [
                    __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],

    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'home' => [
                'type' => Literal::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'createUser' => [
                'type' => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/createuser/:username/:password',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\DbBuilderController::class,
                        'action'     => 'createUser',
                        'username' => '',
                        'password' => ''
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'importTrades' => [
                'type' => Literal::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/importTrades',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\DbBuilderController::class,
                        'action'     => 'importTrades',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'createExchanges' => [
                'type' => Literal::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/createExchanges',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\DbBuilderController::class,
                        'action'     => 'createExchanges',
                    ],
                ],
            ],

        ],
    ],
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\IndexController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
            Controller\DbBuilderController::class => function(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName) {
                $entityManager = $container->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
                $userService = $container->get(\Application\Service\UserService::class);
                return new Controller\DbBuilderController($entityManager, $userService);
            },
        ],

    ],

    'view_manager' => [
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => [
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ],
        'template_path_stack' => [
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ],
    'strategies' => array(
        'ViewJsonStrategy',
    ),
];
```

The factory:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Service\Factory;
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;

class UserServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface {

    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $entityManager = $container->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');

        $user = new \Application\Service\UserService($entityManager);
        return $user;
    }

}
```

The Service:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Service;

class UserService
{
    protected $entityManager;

    function __construct(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function createUser($username, $password)
    {
        $user = new \Application\Entity\User();
        $user->setUserKey($password);
        $user->setUserName($username);
        $user->setIsAdmin(true);

        $this->entityManager->persist($user);
        $this->entityManager->flush();

        return $user;
    }
}
```

Comment: well.. it seems good. i mean the code. Did you tried to call DbBuilderController class via factory?

Comment: Since you didn't share any details on the factory class itself I cannot do more then ask: Is the factory class `\Application\Service\Factory\UserServiceFactory::class` referenced correctly? It could be wrongly named, not in the folder you point to or in some other way wrongly referenced...

Comment: If it was referenced incorrectly, it would throw an error.  I even tried to purposely reference it incorrectly.  I will include it.

Comment: Restart your web server? Opcache can be a pain.

Comment: Do you use module settings cache?

Comment: @MehmetSÖĞÜNMEZ Not on purpose.  I don't think so.  This is a dev machine from the Vagrantfile provided with the skeleton application which I'm also using.

Comment: I restarted the whole machine, but this is up on github and my teammates are having the same issue.

Comment: @Bluebaron skeleton application using module settings cache by default. Prolly that's the problem. It's caching the Module class once it run and doesn't read it again. You have to clear cache folder so application will read it again. You can set "module_map_cache_enabled" and "config_cache_enabled" keys false to inactive cache in your config file.

Comment: They're both set to off in dev mode by default.  I set them off in the only other place I could find, though, and it still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the ZF3 service manager suggests it can't load the factory class, i.e. `class_exists('Application\Service\Factory\UserServiceFactory')` is failing.

Make sure the autoloader is registered for the `Application` namespace, either using the `getAutoloaderConfig` function in Module.php or by adding into the composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Application\\": "module/Application/src/"
    }
},
```

(obviously with the directory changed as necessary) then run composer update.

Maybe also check the directory structure containing `UserServiceFactory` for typos if you're using the `Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader`.